# I am working with asp.net and i try to display multiple div dynamically it working but every time display same slider data

Tags: asp.net

```
#region fillAllData4
    private void fillAllData4()
    {
        clsCategory objCategory = new clsCategory(true);
        clsProductMain objProduct = new clsProductMain(true);
        objCategory.getDropDownMenu();
        objProduct.getProduct();
        string str = string.Empty;
        int i = 0;
        // int j = 0;
        if (objCategory.ListclsCategory.Count > 0)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < objCategory.ListclsCategory.Count; i++)
            {
                cat.InnerHtml = objCategory.ListclsCategory[0].CategoryName;
                cat1.InnerHtml = objCategory.ListclsCategory[1].CategoryName;
                cat2.InnerHtml = objCategory.ListclsCategory[2].CategoryName;
                cat3.InnerHtml = objCategory.ListclsCategory[3].CategoryName;
                string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/images/Saree/"));
                int j = 0;
                foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
                {
                    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                    str += @"<div><div><img class='imges' src='images/Saree/" + fileName + @"' /></div>
                                  <div class='sname'>" + objProduct.ListclsProductMain[j].ProductName + @"</div>
                                 <div class='sname2'>" + objProduct.ListclsProductMain[j].MRP + @"</div></div>";
                    j++;
                }
                slider3.InnerHtml = str;
                slider4.InnerHtml = str;
                slider5.InnerHtml = str;
                slider6.InnerHtml = str;
                //System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl createDiv =
                //new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
                //createDiv.ID = "createDiv";
                //createDiv.InnerHtml =str;
                //this.Controls.Add(createDiv);

            }
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: i want to display category wise block and every block contain category wise product slider and category and sliderdata came from different table

Comment: Well - you're setting the same data for your `slider3` to `slider6` in your code so why do you think it would be different?

Comment: but i want different data but there is no image stored in product table so i retrived it from folder what i will do for diffrenet data

Comment: To be frank - but I think you need to scale down to a minimum, because it seems you struggle a bit with the basic (variable scopes for example); so I'd advice you to start with some programming tutorials and take it from there and when you understand the basics - then start moving forward to what you want to achieve. I'm not saying this to be harsh, but short of coding it for you, it'll be difficult to actually help.